# Android - Why i'm getting fatal signal?

Tags: android, opengl-es

Im trying to display some points on the screen with opengl es.
here is the code of ondraw:

```
gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
gl.glLoadIdentity();
gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
gl.glColor4f(0, 255, 0, 0);     
gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, buffer);
gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_POINTS, 0, points.length);
gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
```

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong???

EDIT: the code to generate the buffer and points

```
    points = new float[12288];
    int pos = 0;
    for (float y = 0; y < 64; y++) {
        for (float x = 0; x < 64; x++) {
            points[pos++] = x/100;
            points[pos++] = y/100;
            points[pos++] = 0;
        }
    }

    ByteBuffer vertexByteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(points.length * 4);
    vertexByteBuffer.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());     
    // allocates the memory from the byte buffer
    buffer = vertexByteBuffer.asFloatBuffer();   
    // fill the vertexBuffer with the vertices
    buffer.put(points);  
    // set the cursor position to the beginning of the buffer
    buffer.position(0);
```

and the error at logcat:

04-17 06:38:11.296: A/libc(24276): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x41719000 (code=2)

This error happens at gl.glDrawArrays

Comment: Can you show the error message or the LogCat?

Comment: Need more code also. Show where buffer, points come from.

Comment: Fatal signal or _exception_? Try enabling breaking at the time the exception is thrown, and see what's going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is the problem:

`gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_POINTS, 0, points.length);`

`glDrawArrays` takes the number of **vertices** that you want to draw. You are giving it the number of **floats**, which is 3x too big. Therefore opengl is actually attempting to read 12288 vertices = 36,xxx floats from your points array, which way exceeds the bounds of your array.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem:** You have not called glBindBuffer but you then called glDrawArrays; this will cause a segfault.

I had the same problem when I tried to use an IBO buffer without first binding the buffer using the glBindBuffer command. For example, one of my draw functions looks like this:

```
GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, common.vbo);
GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, common.ibo);

GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(handleManager.switchPosition, 2, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(handleManager.switchPosition);

GLES20.glDrawElements(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, common.iboPointCount, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);

GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(handleManager.switchPosition);

GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
```

All of the glBindBuffer commands make it possible to operate on the attribute data that you are trying to get the shader to recognise.

Comment: I think you are confusing *vertex arrays* with *vertex buffer objects*. There's not a requirement that you use glBindBuffer to use glDrawArrays. If a buffer is not bound, then the data is read directly from system memory instead of the buffer in video memory.

Comment: @Tim: Hmm, perhaps you are right. I'm going to leave my answer here anyway just in case it helps somebody else that was using VBO's and is wondering why they go the same error...just read your profile. You work at NVIDIA. You are certainly right. Still going to leave the answer here though as I had this problem when I forgot to do what I mentioned while using VBO's. Can't beat an answer from somebody that works on the graphics cards themselves. :D Cheers. +1